# SNS DynamoDB Example

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sns

I have a simple use case.

I am using `S3`, `DynamoDB` now I want to send a message to a device using `SNS`.

This message is triggered by `DynamoDB` update.

How do I do that?

Are there any 'examples' available for this kind of problem?

Comment: SNS examples in Java are at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/using-awssdkjava.html.

Comment: Why don't you just send a push notification from the endpoint that does the update in the DynamoDB table ?.

Answer (score 3):

We use a DynamoDB stream to trigger a Lambda function in JavaScript which then uses SNS to send a message.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct notification(sns) that can be generated by dynamodb update. 
Refer to the Dynamodb streams. It is still in preview mode but will soon be available for all. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html